# jsPlumb's endpoints do not follow rotated DIVs

Tags: javascript, rotation, jsplumb

I am using jsPlumb and there is a need for rotating some divs. However, the end points do not follow the divs after their rotation. Has anybody faced the same problem or something similar to propose some solution/workaround??

Comment: have you tried to repaint after rotating ?

Comment: It does not work with repaint. I am experimenting with the geometry and use `endpoint.anchor.offsets[]` to move endpoints